# Python pip doesn't work when I ask its version

Tags: python, pip

### I have download python 3.10.5 with pip, but when I do this: python -m pip --version, I have this errors:

[image]

## I would like to delete this question because it doesn't look useful for community, because I just didn't think to reinstall Python first.

## But there are many answers here, and I don't want to delete there answers too, so this question will be alive.

### Thanks all of you for looking on this worse question

Comment: Please paste code, data, and error messages here as [code-formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) rather than as [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the python, and all now works good!

Thanks all of you!

Answer (score 2):

Do `pip --version`, not `python -m pip --version`.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
python3 -m pip --version
```

I assume python does not call python 3 but python 2 for which you probably have not installed pip.

Verify this with

```
python --version
python3 --version
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question. I do not understand it :-)